# Is there any mention of practice of writings during Ramayana or Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, sanskrit, language

Did people use to write down things in Sanskrit or Prakrit during Ramayana or Mahabharata period?
Had the concept of written language been invented?